# How to fix "terminate called without an active exception" error in this code?

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, terminate

First of all, I am a student so the code might not be an efficient or well-written one. Sorry for that. But I could use some help if it doesn't bother you.

Following is my main program and musical_chairs function that I use in my main program.

```
void musical_chairs(IntQueueHW6 &my_queue, unsigned int idx,unsigned int remaining_player_num, vector<int> &players)
{

    this_thread::sleep_until(chrono::system_clock::now() + chrono::seconds(2));
    mtx.lock();
    if(!(my_queue.isFull()))
    {
        my_queue.enqueue(idx);// my_queue is a queue with size of total_player_num-1
        cout << "Player " << idx << " captured a chair at ";
        current_time();
        cout << "." << endl;
    }
    else
    //**************** I believe this block causing the error *******************
        not_capture(idx);
        for(int k = 0; k < remaining_player_num; k++)
        {
            if(players[k] == idx)
            {
                players.erase(players.begin()+k);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    mtx.unlock();
//*************** I believe this block causing the error **********************
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int total_player_num, total_round_num, remaining_player_num;
    cout << "Welcome to Musical Chairs game!" << endl << "Enter the number of players in the game: " << endl;
    cin >> total_player_num;
    remaining_player_num = total_player_num;
    total_round_num = total_player_num - 1;
    cout << "Game Start!" << endl << endl;

    vector<int> players(total_player_num); // creating a vector consists of players IDs
    for(int i=0; i < total_player_num; i++)
    {
        players[i] = i;
    }


    while(remaining_player_num != 1) // until only one player left in te game
    {
        IntQueueHW6 my_queue(total_round_num); // creating a queue with size total_round_num for chair slots
        vector<thread> threads(total_player_num); // create a thread vector for all players

        cout << "Time is now ";
        current_time();
        cout << endl;
        int players_length = players.size();

        for(int i = 0; i < players_length; i++)
        {
            int idx = players[i];
            threads[idx] = thread(&musical_chairs, ref(my_queue), idx, remaining_player_num, ref(players));
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < players_length; i++) //joining to threads
        {
            int idx = players[i];
            if(threads[idx].joinable())
            {
                threads[idx].join();
            }
        }
         
        display_remaining_players(players); // changing variables accordingly
        remaining_player_num --;
        total_round_num -- ;
        my_queue.clear();
    }

    unsigned int winner_id = players[0];
    winner_func(winner_id); // this function displays the winner

    return 0;
}
```

I wrote a program that simulates "musical chairs" game with using multi-threading.
When I run the main program I get "terminate called without an active exception" error. Due to my little research on the internet it may be because of threads going out of scope but if it is I do not know how to fix it. Can anyone explain how to solve it? If the error occurs from a different thing can you please explain it and can you help me to fix this code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right now, it doesn't look like your code will even compile (looks like it's missing an opening brace after the `else` on the 13th line). Please put together a minimum example that we can build that demonstrates the problem, then copy and paste it (precisely as-is).

Comment: `my_queue.clear();` -- It's odd you have this at the end of the `while` loop, when `my_queue` is a local variable and will be destroyed anyway every time the loop iterates.

Answer (score 0):

The `std::terminate` is called because a thread is terminating without being joined.

The losing thread in the `musical_chairs` function removes itself from the vector of players, but in the meantime the `main` thread has continued executing, looping over the threads calling `join`. The lack of synchronization here will cause this to fail in random ways depending on the vagaries of thread scheduling.

Given the code structure, this will take a re-think to fix. The following is the simplest implementation I could come up with. It uses `std::atomic` instead of `std::mutex` which is much more efficient.

A couple of quick notes:

- I chose a `std::set` instead of a `std::vector` for the players because the player ids are unique and it is much easier and more efficient to remove an element from a set than a vector.
- To make the game fairer, I chose the `middle` thread as the loser in each round -- otherwise, the last thread was losing too often.
- The lambda capture for the thread creation is subtle. The `pid` must be captured by value so that each thread will have its own player id, but the `queue`, `chairs`, and `loser` need to be captured by reference because they are all shared across threads.

### Sample Code

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <set>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using std::cin, std::cout, std::endl;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

using PlayerId = int;
using Queue = std::queue<PlayerId>;
using Players = std::set<PlayerId>;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    int initial_number_players{};
    cin >> initial_number_players;

    Players players;
    for (auto i = 0; i < initial_number_players; ++i)
        players.insert(i);

    while (players.size() > 1) {
        Queue queue;
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;

        std::atomic<int> chairs{}, loser{};
        for (auto pid : players) {
            threads.emplace_back([&,pid]() {
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(250ms);
                auto cid = chairs.fetch_add(1);
                if (cid == players.size() / 2)
                    loser = pid;
            });
        }
        for (auto& th : threads)
            if (th.joinable())
                th.join();

        cout << "Player " << loser << " did not capture a chair" << endl;
        players.erase(loser);
    }

    cout << "Player " << *players.begin() << " won" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
Player 8 did not capture a chair
Player 0 did not capture a chair
Player 1 did not capture a chair
Player 2 did not capture a chair
Player 6 did not capture a chair
Player 3 did not capture a chair
Player 5 did not capture a chair
Player 4 did not capture a chair
Player 9 did not capture a chair
Player 7 won
```